# I got python cx freeze issue

Tags: python, cx-freeze

What's wrong in my application?

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ ~~~~~ \ Python36\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your cx_Freeze version to [5.1.1 or the latest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/5.1.1) by running:

```
pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

and your error should fix.

This problem was fixed in the latest version as described on the cx_Freeze GitHub page: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/325